# checking multiple cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using two NSMutable Arrays for storing multiple checkmarks..**repeatDaysToStore** and **data1**.
This is the code in viewDidLoad method...

```
for (int i=1; i<=[repeatDaysToStore count]; i++) 


{

    BOOL isTheObjectThere = [repeatArray containsObject:[repeatDaysToStore objectAtIndex:(i-1)]];

    if (isTheObjectThere) 
    {

        NSString *into=[repeatArray objectAtIndex:[repeatArray indexOfObject:[repeatDaysToStore objectAtIndex:(i-1)]]];


              [data1 addObject:into];

        NSLog(@"check did load");

    }



}
```

and after this I am using data1 array for checking the cells...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {

    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
 cell.textLabel.text=[repeatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection=YES;
 for (int j=1; j<=[data1 count]; j++) {
     NSLog(@"%d",[[data1 objectAtIndex:(j-1)]intValue]);
       NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
   if([data1 indexOfObject:[data1 objectAtIndex:(j-1)]]==indexPath.row)
     {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 } 
 else
  {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }

  }
```

and for handling row selections I am using this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
      { 
        NSString *myobj=[repeatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
      if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [repeatDaysToStore removeObject:myobj];
        [data1 removeObject:myobj];


    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [repeatDaysToStore addObject:myobj];
        [data1 addObject:myobj];

    }
[tableView reloadData];
 }
```

but its not working.Someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Please describe "not working".  What are the symptoms?

Comment: When I select a single cell it works after that when I select the next cell it does nothing,and if I click on another cell,it selects the previous cell...

Comment: I am confused.
Is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method's following code:

```
for (int j=1; j<=[data1 count]; j++)
{
     NSLog(@"%d",[[data1 objectAtIndex:(j-1)]intValue]);
     NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
   if([data1 indexOfObject:[data1 objectAtIndex:(j-1)]]==indexPath.row)
   {
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   } 
   else
   {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }
}
```

Remove the code and write the condition like:

```
if([data1 containsObject:[repeatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
{
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} 
else
{
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Also remove the `[tableView reloadData];` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: thnx alot...
but there is no need to remove `[tableview reloadData]`

Comment: @toofani: if you write `[tableview reloadData]`. It'll reload the tableView when you select each item. Which will cause performance issue. If it is working without `[tableview reloadData]`. Then remove that code :)

Comment: @Midhun...but if u remove `[tableView reloadData]` then the selection is changed only after view is reloaded...and cells become blue...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a less-complicated data structure to make this work in a way that's easy to understand.

The data for your table should be an array of objects.  Each object should contain at least two properties: one is the information you're going to show in `cell.textLabel.text` and the other is a `BOOL` property that says whether or not the object is selected.

When a row is selected, set the `BOOL` to the opposite of what it currently is and reload your table.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just use the current setting of the object for the requested row without going through a secondary array.